# template not found in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using django 1.4

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

```
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
    /home/user/mysite/template/<WSGIRequest path:/polls/what/, GET:<QueryDict: {}>, POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
```

Using `pwd` I see this:

```
/home/user/mysite/template
```

Within `template I have`polls`

This is what I put in `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/user/mysite/template',
```

Now in my views:

```
return render_to_response(request, 'polls/index.html',
```

Why is it still complaining?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This may not be your only problem, but [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) takes the template name first, then the context and context instance.

try this

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def view_name(request):
    # view code 
    return render_to_response('polls/index.html',
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

or, as suggested in the comments, you meant to use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def view_name(request):
    # view code 
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html')
```

but also make sure that you have a template called index.html in polls in template

```
myapp/
    myapp/
        ...
        settings.py
        template/
            polls/
                index.html
```

Comment: The OP is probably intending to use the new `render` shortcut, which *does* take the request first.

Comment: yeah ... `render(request, 'polls/index.html')` would work without the need of `RequestContext`

Answer (score 0):

Add slash

```
return render_to_response(request, '/polls/index.html',
```